# Put a frame around table notes

Tags: tables, tabularx

I created a table and I added some notes to some cells. I was wondering
if it is possible to put a frame around the table notes. The frame should have the same size as the the table. At the end I added a small example of my table. The original table has more entries and is  fixed to the page width.

Cheers

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{0pt}} llc} 
\hline
Col1 & Col2 & Col3\tnote{1} \\
1 &    2 &    3\tnote{2} \\
4 &    5 &    6\tnote{3} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx} 
\begin{tablenotes}
    \item[1] FRAME ME 1
    \item[2] FRAME ME 2
    \item[3] FRAME ME 3
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: will `\fbox{FRAME ME 1}` do the job?

Comment: Sorry, my example was maybe misleading. I wanted to put a frame around all the nodes. \fbox{} around \begin{tablenotes}.. etc. didn't work for met

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tcolorbox` is your new friend. About the various ways to customise it, see its documentation.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{0pt}} llc} 
\hline
Col1 & Col2 & Col3\tnote{1} \\
1 &    2 &    3\tnote{2} \\
4 &    5 &    6\tnote{3} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx} 

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{tablenotes}
    \item[1] FRAME ME 1
    \item[2] FRAME ME 2
    \item[3] FRAME ME 3
\end{tablenotes}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{threeparttable}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For simple frames, you can use the  `framed` environment:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{3}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
Col1 & Col2 & Col3\tnote{1} \\
\addlinespace
1 & 2 & 3\tnote{2} \\
4 & 5 & 6\tnote{3} \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\end{tabularx}
\setlength\FrameSep{5pt}
\begin{tablenotes}
\begin{framed}
    \item[1] FRAME ME 1
    \item[2] FRAME ME 2
    \item[3] FRAME ME 3
\end{framed}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

[image]