# Add table borders around notes created with package 'threeparttablex'

Tags: tables, longtable, threeparttable, tablenotes, threeparttablex

I need to create a table with notes having the borders like this:

[image]

I use the package *threeparttablex* and it works perfectly for me. The only issue is that I do not know how to keep borders around the notes. The best I was able to do is this (see MWE below):

[image]

Can you please help me find ways to add all borders?

(I know there is an alternative [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317018/put-a-frame-around-table-notes) to add a frame, but I want to make use of the original table borders.)

The minimal working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
        \item[a] Note A
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}[c]{ | c | c | }
        \caption{Example}\\\hline
        Left & Right \\\hline\hline
        \endhead
        % Below command gives only bottom border
        \insertTableNotes\\\hline
        % I want borders on all sides like this
        %\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textsuperscript{a} Note A}\\\hline
        \endlastfoot
        sample text & text\tnote{a} \\
        more text & text \\\hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the problem using the commented multicolumn instead of the TablesNotes, that are designed to be *out* of the table ? BTW, I would consider use either `tcolorbox` and/or `booktabs` instead of "jailed tables".

Comment: @Fran I am neither familiar with `tcolorbox` nor `booktabs`. Will definitely have a look. Thank you! For now, I am not sure what you mean by "jailed tables".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\insertTableNotes` does `\multicolumn{<number of cols>}{c}{...}`; you can patch it to use `{|c|}` instead.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd\insertTableNotes{{c}}{{|c|}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
        \item[a] Note A\strut
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}[c]{ | c | c | }
        \caption{Example}\\\hline
        Left & Right \\\hline\hline
        \endhead
        % Below command gives only bottom border
        \insertTableNotes\\\hline
        \endlastfoot
        sample text & text\tnote{a} \\
        more text & text \\\hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Add a `\strut` at the end of the last table note.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm! I will also try to explore what can be done with `tcolorbox` and `booktabs` as Fran suggested. There is always so much to learn :)